# Run an Azure pipeline as administrator or disable UAC

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to execute tests in my pipeline like so:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:  
- stage: Build_and_Test
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  displayName: Execute Tests
  jobs:
    - job: ExecuteTests
      steps:
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Execute Win32 Tests
          inputs:
            command: 'test'
            projects: 'Tests\Project.Tests.csproj'
            arguments: '--filter "FullyQualifiedName~Win32"'            
            testRunTitle: 'Win32 Tests'
```

One of my tests executes an .exe which I need to run as administrator. Alternatively, I need  to disable UAC on the executing instance.

Are either of these options possible?

Answer (score 0):

The MS hosted Windows agents have provided the capability to **`run as an administrator`** (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations)).

For your case, if you want to run a program with administrator permissions, you can try the following steps to see if it can work:

1. Open the **`Properties`** window of this program on your local machine and go to the **`Compatibility`** tab.
2. At the bottom of the window, check the "**`Run this program as an administrator`**" option.
3. Click **`Apply`** and **`OK`** button to save the change.

With above way, this program will always run with administrator permissions.

If above way does not work for you, I recommend you use the local administrator account as authentication (see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#required-options)) to install a [**Self-hosted Windows agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local Windows machine to run the job.